# I'm trying to get clarification on a different answer from three years ago regarding "SteamAuth var from startup.auth to the view ASP.NET"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, owin-security

I realize that this may be a bit old, but i'm trying to do the same as the original question. That can be seen here: 
[SteamAuth var from startup.auth to the view ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33475737/steamauth-var-from-startup-auth-to-the-view-asp-net)

I have written everything that you have, but the 'Steam.Models.ApplicationDbContext()' isn't working for me.

Is that something that is only present within MY project, making it a naming convention error, or something else?

If someone knows of a way to get the information that is return from app.UseSteamAuthentication(API Key); that would work too.

Also the link to the tutorial is returning a 404 error. I'd like to look at if it's still available.

Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: That question was asked 3 years ago, there is a fair chance that the protocols have changed since then. Please include all relevant code in **this** question. It's hard to see exactly what your having difficulty with if you don't show us what **you've** tried. A link to an old question saying I've done this isn't very helpful

Comment: I've added a steam login button to my webpage adding the line "app.UseSteamAuthentication(<<API Key>>);" to my startup.auth.cs file

This allows me to login, but I cant figure how to get the info that is being passed back to me. I followed what the user said 3 years ago, but the line that I mentioned in my question does not work for me. Is that because it refers to a specific file in the project that doesn't exist in mine, or am I missing something?

Comment: Edit the question